# Facing BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field and SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field and SOLID_FOREGROUND cannot be resolved or is not a field.

My original Generic.java file:

```
package com.expertus.libraries;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

//import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class Generic {
    public static int getRowCount(String xlPath, String sheetName) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return -1;
        }

    }

    public static String getCellValue(String xlPath, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, int cellNum) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static int getColumnCount(String xlPath, String sheetName, int rowNum) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getLastCellNum();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void setCellValue(String xlPath, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, int cellNum, String cellVal) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Row r = wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum);
            if (r == null)
                r = wb.getSheet(sheetName).createRow(rowNum);
            Cell c = r.getCell(cellNum);
            if (c == null)
                c = r.createCell(cellNum);
            c.setCellValue(cellVal);
            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(xlPath);
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }

    }

    public static void writeRes(String fisPath, HashMap hm) 
    {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fisPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

            Sheet mainSheet = wb.getSheet("Main");
            int rc = mainSheet.getLastRowNum();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rc; i++) {
                String module = mainSheet.getRow(i).getCell(0)
                        .getStringCellValue();
                Sheet testCaseSheet = wb.getSheet(module);
                int rowCnt = testCaseSheet.getLastRowNum();
                for (int j = 1; j <= rowCnt; j++) {
                    String testcase = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).getCell(0)
                            .getStringCellValue();
                    Set<String> key = hm.keySet();
                    for (String k : key) {
                        if (testcase.equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {
                            Cell c = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).getCell(2);
                            if (c == null)
                                c = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).createCell(2);
                            String value = hm.get(k).toString();
                            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont = wb.createFont();

                                headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                                CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
                                headerStyle
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());

                                headerStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

                            } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("SKIP")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont2 = wb.createFont();

                                headerFont2.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                                CellStyle headerStyle2 = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle2.setFont(headerFont2);
                                headerStyle2
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont2.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());
                                headerStyle2.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle2);

                            } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont1 = wb.createFont();
                                headerFont1.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                                CellStyle headerStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle1.setFont(headerFont1);
                                headerStyle1
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont1.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());
                                headerStyle1.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle1);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream("./Results/Results " + curDate()
                    + ".xlsx");
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // returns current date with time
    public static String curDate() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // returns current date
    public static String date() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // returns past date
    public static String past_furure_Date(int i) {
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -i);
        String pastDate = date.format(gc.getTime());
        return pastDate;
    }

    public static void takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver, String name)
            throws IOException {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        //FileUtils
        //      .copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshot\\" + name + ".png"));

    }

    // to delete .png files in screenshot folder
    public static void deleteRecursive(File path) {
        File[] c = path.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Cleaning out folder:" + path.toString());
        for (File file : c) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Deleting file:" + file.toString());
                deleteRecursive(file);
                file.delete();
            } else {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I browsed and found 2 solutions as follows
headerFont1.setBold(true);
headerStyle1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

My modified Generic.java file:

```
package com.expertus.libraries;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

//import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class Generic {
    public static int getRowCount(String xlPath, String sheetName) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return -1;
        }

    }

    public static String getCellValue(String xlPath, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, int cellNum) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static int getColumnCount(String xlPath, String sheetName, int rowNum) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            return wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum).getLastCellNum();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void setCellValue(String xlPath, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, int cellNum, String cellVal) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Row r = wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(rowNum);
            if (r == null)
                r = wb.getSheet(sheetName).createRow(rowNum);
            Cell c = r.getCell(cellNum);
            if (c == null)
                c = r.createCell(cellNum);
            c.setCellValue(cellVal);
            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(xlPath);
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }

    }

    public static void writeRes(String fisPath, HashMap hm) 
    {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try 
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fisPath);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

            Sheet mainSheet = wb.getSheet("Main");
            int rc = mainSheet.getLastRowNum();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rc; i++) {
                String module = mainSheet.getRow(i).getCell(0)
                        .getStringCellValue();
                Sheet testCaseSheet = wb.getSheet(module);
                int rowCnt = testCaseSheet.getLastRowNum();
                for (int j = 1; j <= rowCnt; j++) {
                    String testcase = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).getCell(0)
                            .getStringCellValue();
                    Set<String> key = hm.keySet();
                    for (String k : key) {
                        if (testcase.equalsIgnoreCase(k)) {
                            Cell c = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).getCell(2);
                            if (c == null)
                                c = testCaseSheet.getRow(j).createCell(2);
                            String value = hm.get(k).toString();
                            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont = wb.createFont();

                                headerFont.setBold(true);

                                CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
                                headerStyle
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());
                                headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);


                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

                            } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("SKIP")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont2 = wb.createFont();
                                headerFont2.setBold(true);

                                CellStyle headerStyle2 = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle2.setFont(headerFont2);
                                headerStyle2
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont2.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());

                                headerStyle2.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle2);

                            } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {

                                c.setCellValue(hm.get(k).toString());

                                Font headerFont1 = wb.createFont();
                                headerFont1.setBold(true);

                                CellStyle headerStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
                                headerStyle1.setFont(headerFont1);
                                headerStyle1
                                        .setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED
                                                .getIndex());
                                headerFont1.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK
                                        .getIndex());

                                headerStyle1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                                c.setCellStyle(headerStyle1);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream("./Results/Results " + curDate()
                    + ".xlsx");
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // returns current date with time
    public static String curDate() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // returns current date
    public static String date() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    // returns past date
    public static String past_furure_Date(int i) {
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -i);
        String pastDate = date.format(gc.getTime());
        return pastDate;
    }

    public static void takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver, String name)
            throws IOException {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        //FileUtils
        //      .copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshot\\" + name + ".png"));

    }

    // to delete .png files in screenshot folder
    public static void deleteRecursive(File path) {
        File[] c = path.listFiles();
        System.out.println("Cleaning out folder:" + path.toString());
        for (File file : c) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Deleting file:" + file.toString());
                deleteRecursive(file);
                file.delete();
            } else {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to execute now, I am facing Null Pointer Exception.

I am using apache poi 4.1.1 and apache poi-ooxml 4.1.1

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 11):

Although this is an old question and the OP has most probably solved it, it came up first in a google search for same issue and I thought to add my solution in case it helps anyone.

For poi 4.1.7 I used `font.setBold( true )` instead of <s>`font.setBoldweight( Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD )`</s>

To put it into the context of the post's question, the author could change their code

From:
<s>`headerFont2.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);`</s>

To:
`headerFont.font.setBold( true );`

Given that they have also imnported Font class:

`import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;`